# How to use not exists in a sql query with w3schools?

Tags: sql, not-exists

I have an issue with `not exists` sql query at [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/trysql.asp?filename=trysql_select_like)

I want to `select` all customers that work with `shipperid = 1` BUT not `shipperid = 3`.
I tried the following:

```
select o1.customerid, o1.shipperid
from orders o1
where o1.shipperid=1 and not exists
(select o2.customerid from orders o2
where o1.orderid=o2.orderid
and o2.shipperid=3)
order by customerid
;
```

The above query gives all customers that work with `shipperid = 1` and does NOT exclude customers who work with `shipperid = 3`. What is not correct with the query. *(I need to speifically use `not exists`)*

---

PS: I know the `in` solution:

```
select customerid, shipperid
from orders
where shipperid=1 and customerid not in (
select customerid
from orders
where shipperid=3
)
order by customerid;
```

Why does not the `not exists` solution work?

Comment: You should be interested by [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/173041/not-in-vs-not-exists) in you already know `in`

Comment: I still don't understand the question. What's wrong with the `NOT EXISTS`(note that it's better than `NOT IN`, see: http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/12/t-sql-queries/left-anti-semi-join).

Comment: The problem is that it does not work for me. For example I get `customerid` number 4 who works with shipperid number 1 as well as number 3. I do not know what is the problem with my `not exists` query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm fairly certain that the problem lies in the way you're joining the correlated subquery, on orderid = orderid.  I'm not familiar with this dataset, but it seems surprising that the same order would have different shippers, and it adds a condition not found in your 'correct' answer.  This should work:

```
select o1.customerid
      ,o1.shipperid
from orders as o1
where o1.shipperid = 1 
and not exists (
    select o2.orderid 
    from orders as o2
    where o1.customerid = o2.customerid
    and o2.shipperid = 3)
order by customerid
;
```